# How to optimize Java multithreading code (SWT)

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, optimization, swt

I'm coding a GUI application in SWT and I've got code that looks like that:

```
button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
         @Override
         public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e) {

         ... lot of variable initialization from text fields etc.

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {

               ... more than 400 lines of code

               display.asyncExec() everywhere ...

      }).start();
   }
}
```

Is there some way to optimize this kind of code?
I'd like to move the thread to its own class but then, how do I get all of the Component values without hassle?

Comment: This is not really a question about multithreading, about user interfaces, about optimization or, about SWT.  What you really are asking is, I've got this big huge class that I want to break up into smaller classes, how do I do it?  In other words, how do I _refactor_ code?  There are whole books about that.  Kind of hard to give an answer that fits this forum.

Comment: Agree james, but I didn't know how to "create" a good question!
Still I think my problem is focused on a specific subject.

Answer (score 1):

make a nested class at the end of the class:

```
public class Someclass{
    //main code here

    class Nestedclass implements Runnable{
        //thread code here
    }
}
```

that way the code will be devided to two parts and easier to read, and the nested class could still access all global variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I like that approach, but still a different .java source file would be my preferred option!

Comment: to get a different .java source file, first provide your initial variant. The code you inserted does not compile.

Comment: Eclipse IDE has option Refactor->Convert anonymous class to nested. I am sure other IDEs has similar functionality. This way you can convert both extentions to Runnable as well as that of SelectionEvent .